ubuntu 24.10 - Ненормально выводится звук на наушники
Иногда при включении системы и подключенных проводных наушниках звук выводится и на наушники, и на динамики ноутбука, причем в панели со звуком отображается только наушники. При отключении звук выводится на динамики, но система продолжает думать, что звук идёт на наушники. Случается в основном когда я перезагружаюсь с Windows 10 (Ubuntu поставлена у меня в дуалбуте), но не всегда.
